# Regular expression - street address pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that contains a bunch of data, including street addresses.
I am trying to extract the addresses by making a regular expression.

The addresses are of the form:
"34 rue Roveré"
or
"432 Downhill road"

So always 1 to 3 digits numbers, followed by 1 space, followed by 1 to N words seperated by a space. No punctuation. Notice the words can have letters with accents. Ex: é è  etc. That is why I put unicode codes in my regex.

So far my Regex looks like this :
[0-9]{1,2}\s([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+\s*)+

But I end up with lines of text data that look like this :
"34 44   55 rue du therne, 04 84 98" 
And I would like the regex to only match: "55 rue du therne"

But my current expression also matches the text around the address.
I'm trying things out on http://rubular.com/ but can't seem to finish it correctly to do what I need.

Any help will be appreciated. I am not experienced with regex, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution for `re` module

Since Python doesn't support simple syntax to match any character in Unicode Letter category, we have to workaround by listing the ranges that contain the characters we want to allow.

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+
```

Sample runs:

```
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+', s).group(0)
'55 rue du therne'
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+', "xxx 35 rue Hote de ma maison, 060 06 ").group(0)
'35 rue Hote de ma maison'
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+', "xxx 34 rue Roveré").group(0)
'34 rue Roveré'
```

### Solution for [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2014.12.24)

However, the solution above is not extensible to characters in different languages. If you don't mind installing external [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2014.12.24) module, then you can use `\p{L}` to match any letter from any kind of language.

```
\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s\p{L}+)+
```

`[0-9]{1,3}` matches one or two or three digit number. `\s\p{L}+` matches a space and one or more letters. Likewise `(?:\s\p{L}+)+` `+` after the non-capturing group would repeat the pattern inside the non-capturing group one or more times.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/6)

To use this, you need to import `regex` module instead of `re` module.

```
>>> reg = regex.compile(r'\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s\p{L}+)+')
>>> reg.search("xxx 35 rue Hote de ma maison, 060 06 ").group(0)
'35 rue Hote de ma maison'
>>> reg.search('"xxx 34 rue Roveré').group(0)
'34 rue Roveré'
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. Could you explain the second part of the regex? Thanks!

Comment: \b just means the pattern left border starts at that point? What does "?:" do?

Comment: `(?:..)` called non-capturing group. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Comment: The regex works on Rubular but not from my Python script.
Test code:

import re
p = re.compile(r'\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s\p{L}+)+')
m = p.search("xxx 35 rue Hote de ma maison, 060 06 ")
print(m.group(0))

I get :
m = None  ==>  no match

Comment: Is there a regular expression solution that is compatible with the **re** standard Python module? Or is this more difficult? Thanks.

Comment: this `re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+', s).group(0)` would compatible with `re` module.

Comment: Thanks for the post update about the re compatible expression.
\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+   seems to work on the address patterns but it also picks up phone patterns like this (with no letters) :
**01 02 03 04 05**
Can this be avoided? 
    >>> import re
    >>> p = re.compile(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+')
    >>> m = p.search("01 02 03 ")
    >>> m.group()
    '01 02 03'

Comment: Accept this question and ask the above comment as another question.